# ImageView not displaying the image, but same method to fetch image works in other parts of app

Tags: android, image, listview, bitmap, imageview

I have 3 `ImageViews` in a `ListView row`, but they are not showing up for some reason.

I am using the same function to retrieve the image in another part of the app and it gets the image with no issue. So the method of retrieving the image bitmap is not the issue.

What else could cause an image to not show up in an `ImageView`? I debugged and the `File` was not null.

Please help!

**BaseAdapter that shows the images in the getView method**

```
                try {
                    if (user.getGameOwned().size() > 0) {
                        String coverPhotoName = user.getGameOwned().get(0).getCoverPhoto();
                        if (coverPhotoName != null) {
                            ImageHelper.loadOrDownloadGameCover(mContext, coverPhotoName,
                                    holder.iv2, holder.gameCoverSpinner1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                try {
                    if (user.getGameOwned().size() > 1) {
                        String coverPhotoName = user.getGameOwned().get(1).getCoverPhoto();
                        if (coverPhotoName != null) {
                            ImageHelper.loadOrDownloadGameCover(mContext, coverPhotoName,
                                    holder.iv3, holder.gameCoverSpinner2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                try {
                    if (user.getGameOwned().size() > 2) {
                        String coverPhotoName = user.getGameOwned().get(2).getCoverPhoto();
                        if (coverPhotoName != null) {
                            ImageHelper.loadOrDownloadGameCover(mContext, coverPhotoName,
                                    holder.iv4, holder.gameCoverSpinner3);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

**Method that fetches the image as a bitmap**

```
public static void loadOrDownloadGameCover(final Context context, final String coverPhotoName,
                                           ImageView gameCover, final ProgressBar loadingSpinner) {

    if (isGameCoverDownloaded(context, coverPhotoName)) {
        loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        try {
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    coverPhotoName);
            gameCover.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    else {
        String uri = GlobalVars.URL_GAME_COVER_DOWNLOAD + coverPhotoName;
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, gameCover, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                saveGameCover(context, coverPhotoName, loadedImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**XML of ListView row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/card_white_selector"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/avatar_bg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.walintukai.lovelup.widgets.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/CardUsernameTextView" />

                <com.walintukai.lovelup.widgets.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/details"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/CardUserDetailsTextView" />

                <com.walintukai.lovelup.widgets.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/CardUserDetailsTextView" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.walintukai.lovelup.widgets.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/games_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cover_one"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/cover_one_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cover_two"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/cover_two_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cover_three"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/cover_three_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your layout XML. The `layout_weight` parameter can only be used when the *immediate* parent is a `LinearLayout`, but the immediate parent of your `ImageView` is a `FrameLayout`. Try moving your `layout_weight` values into the `FrameLayout`, like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/cover_one_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/cover_two_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cover_three"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/cover_three_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

You might need to play around with the `ImageView` parameters a bit more to get them to look right, but hopefully they will at least appear now.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solved it. Haha I guess I should've paid attention to the `yellow highlighted line` in Android Studio! Totally missed it.